# What's the best way to program Wi-Fi connection on a Linux system on embedded device?

Tags: wifi, embedded-linux

I have an embedded device with Linux system and I am wondering if I wanna implement the Wi-Fi connection programmably(now I'm using C++), what is the best way?
I've check some reference and found:

1. use **system()/popen(**) functions to call the commands directly. But it caused many problems for many people who used it.
2. use **dbus** interface

I didn't find any api for wireless connection like that under windows platform.

Comment: why do you want to reinvent network manager? https://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/ . In any case, for the dbus interface, you probably shall study its code

Comment: thanks. in our own app, there's no way to use the NetworkManager directly.